# How to retrieve large data from oracle database using vbscript

Tags: sql, oracle, vbscript

I'm now working on vbscript to do some test. Actuelly, I want to retrieve a large amount of data from an oracle database, so I write the code like this:

```
sql = "Select * from CORE_DB where MC = '" & mstr & "' "
Set myrs = db_execute_query(curConnection, sql)
```

Then I count the rows in **myrs**,there are 248 rows. So then I do a **For** loop to retrieve some fields of each row.

```
For k = 0 To db_get_rows_count(myrs)
```

But then I found that the content of the row **k** when **k > 133** was always equal to **k = 133**. So this makes an error.

The **db_execute_query** function is like

```
Function db_execute_query ( byRef curSession , SQL)
 set rs = curSession.Execute( SQL )
 set db_execute_query = rs
End Function
```

The **db_get_rows_count** function is like

```
Function db_get_rows_count( byRef curRS )
  dim rows
  rows = 0
  db_get_rows_count = rows
  curRS.MoveFirst
  Do Until curRS.EOF
    rows = rows+1
    curRS.MoveNext
  Loop
  db_get_rows_count = rows
End Function
```

As I think, there may be a limit size of **mrys** ? Could anyone light me about this? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the `db_execute_query` and `db_get_rows_count` functions do.  Most likely that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Cheran, Ok, I edit the question to give some details on these two fucntions. Thanks

Comment: Could anyone please give ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to know what's actually in the database.  Can you connect to your database using some other tool (SQLPlus, PL/SQL Developer, Toad, etc) and execute your query?  And if you do so, do the results match those that you get when you execute your query through VBScript?

Also, do you get an error from the database?  That might help determine what's going on.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have verified in the database the expected result, but I haven't execute a sql query in another tool yet. Anyway, I haven't got any error.

Comment: Hello, I have tested using SQL Developer, the result is correct, so I think It's maybe the problem of my statements of VBScript

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm wondering why you're iterating through the result set to find out how many rows were returned by the query, and then you're going back to process the rows.  I suggest that you shouldn't bother counting the rows, just process them as you get them.  If you really need to count them before you process the data, you need to be sure there's a curRS.MoveFirst done sometime after you call db_get_rows_count and before you start looking at rows in the result set again.

Comment: yes, I do realize that it is no so efficient, anyway, I checked the existence of curRs.MoveFirst. But still I want to know that if there is a size limit of "rs". If so, how can I define several "rs" to store the search results?